# How to write data to both NoSQL and RDBMS simultaneously and efficiently

Tags: mongodb, architecture, nosql, rdbms

Let’s assume a setup where a mobile application is communicating with its backend via an API, and data resulting from this communication (eg JSON- based transaction writes among others) is written into and read from a MongoDB instance.

Now since I would like to perform some heavy analytics on data stored in mongo, should I rather:

- save data directly to RDBMS at the same time as I write to Mongo (so the backend service calls Mongo and after successful write also calls RDBMS)
- perform read from Mongo (with some intervals) and load fresh data into RDBMS

I am afraid that both of those solutions require also re-engineering theoretically schema-less Mongo to be in constant agreement with relations and schema in RDBMS. Does it really require more planning for any document structure changes in Mongo? I intuitively say yes, but I look for real world examples. I hope my point is clear enough.

Comment: It's not clear why you absolutely need MongoDB in the 1st place. Can you rethink using Elassandra (Cassandra + ES) instead?

Comment: Can you elaborate why should I consider change? Mongo has been selected by developers as primary app backend, I need to enhance architecture for advanced analytics.

Comment: Considering NoSQL should be highly tailored to suit your needs and ideally should be weighed in by Architects, well ideally, :-)... Structured/Un-structured data, Writes/Reads, Latency, Infra, CAP trade-offs, master-driven or peer-to-peer architecture, lock-in on architectural complexity etc... each NoSQL Soln has it's own pro's and cons. W/O knowing your UC it's not really possible to suggest otherwise; You can consider using Apache Spark + MongoDB for analytics. If you want to have high writes/ strong analytics, you should consider using Cassandra+Spark instead of Cassandra+ElasticSearch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few constraints that need to be understood before you embark on a solution here.  The most relevant of these is latency.  How out-of-date can your data be?

You are almost definitely looking at some kind of write-behind solution here, taking data out of MongoDB, and writing it to your data warehouse.  The question is, how far behind your MongoDB can your data warehouse be?  Many solutions based on an extract-transform-load model (ETL) work on a nightly basis, so as to minimize impact on the online system.  Some can do the same on an hourly basis, but will have more potential impact on the live system.

Transaction-by-transaction support is likely not needed for an analysis system.  You really want to avoid this if you can, as it puts far more load on both systems than is usually justified.

To answer your second question, yes, once you start depending on a schema, it needs to be stable.  It doesn't have to be synced up with your target schema necessarily, but your ETL process will have to be aware of both, and will have to be modified any time either one materially changes.  Being "schema-less" doesn't mean there isn't a schema, it just means that the schema is not enforced by the software, instead it is enforced by the dependencies on the system.

Comment: I like your answer very much (since this confirms my initial thoughts). Could you please comment on this Kafka solution from another answer? Does “reading the MongoDB changes from the oplog in near-real time” puts additional load on Mongo DB to the extent you had in mind? I understand reading from log is not the same as reading from DB.

Comment: Agreed, but the log can have I/O constraints as well.  Additionally, there is *definitely* going to be more load on the target server as records are replayed.  Finally, as you are streaming events from the oplog, it is very likely you will have to hit your live datastore to get additional data in order to write it correctly to the database.  This will incur load as well.  Relational & NoSQL are rarely 1-1 in their schema layouts (they shouldn't be!), so it will take some massaging to make it fit.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe CQRS pattern will be good for You.
See: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

You can use RDBMS for Write Model. Mongo - for Read Model. 
After every write operation to RDBMS You should update Your ReadModel (MongoDB Document) based on data from Write Model.

Answer (score 1):

I think the option with least engineering effort is to use a Kafka connector for MongoDB, such that the connector will read the MongoDB changes from the oplog in near-real time and write the event in Kafka. Then from Kafka you can write the data to a relational DB using a stream processing.

Dual write from UI is not a good option as it can introduce latency, complexity and opeeational overhead. What if the write to one DB fails?